# Recursive tree search to get the node level

Tags: python, r, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a dataset that contains a tree similar to the tree below.

```
  son father
1   1     NA
2   2      1
3   3      1
4   4      2
5   5     NA
6   6      2
7   7      4
8   8      5
9   9      4
```

Built a function that allows me to search the entire hierarchy of a node (son)

```
getTree = function(sons){
   if( length(sons) > 0 ){
      sons = subset(df, father %in% sons)[['son']]
      sons = c(sons, getTree( sons ))
   }

   return(sons)
}

subset(df, son %in% getTree(8))
```

That returns me

```
  son father
4   4      2
6   6      2
7   7      4
9   9      4
```

However, in addition to the hierarchy, it is necessary to know at which level of the tree that node (child) is. How do I change, or create another function that allows me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just need a depth counter argument in your function that you increment by 1 on each recursive call.

Comment: Thank you Randy! I even tried this idea, I just couldn't pass this counter in the function call. How could that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your function is meant to find in the tree, but here's an example in Python that finds the deepest children nodes in the table along with the depth. It uses a incremented counter on each call that keeps track of the depth:

```
In [140]: def traverse(sons, depth=0):
     ...:     next_sons = sons[sons['father'].isin(sons['son'])]
     ...:     if len(next_sons) > 0:
     ...:         return traverse(next_sons, depth+1)
     ...:     return sons, depth

In [141]: traverse(df)
Out[141]:
(   son  father
 7    7     4.0
 9    9     4.0,
 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here might be one recursive option for your to keep the track of node level using `data.frame`, i.e.,

```
f <- function(sons) {
  getTree <- function(s.df) {
    repeat {
      sons <- subset(
        df,
        father %in% s.df$sons[s.df$lvl == max(s.df$lvl)]
      )[["son"]]
      if (length(sons) == 0) {
        return(s.df)
      }
      p <- data.frame(sons = sons, lvl = max(s.df$lvl) + 1)
      s.df <- rbind(s.df, getTree(p))
    }
  }
  getTree(data.frame(sons = sons, lvl = 0))
}
```

where the levels always start from `0` for the input argument `sons` to function `f`, such that

```
> f(1)
  sons lvl
1    1   0
2    2   1
3    3   1
4    4   2
5    6   2
6    7   3
7    9   3

> f(2)
  sons lvl
1    2   0
2    4   1
3    6   1
4    7   2
5    9   2

> f(5)
  sons lvl
1    5   0
2    8   1
```